# Не понимаю, как запустить проект на node js

Tags: php, node.js

Я фрилансер, выполняю заказ. Проект писал не я, от меня требуется только написать авторизацию/регистрацию и мелкие фишки для сайта, работа на php.
Я уже закончил работу, и хочу пофиксить баги, но не знаю как запустить проект т.к никогда не работал с файлами Phar, Composer, PHPUnit, Webpack. Заранее огромное спасибо.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Почитайте как работать с node.js и менеджером пакетов npm. Обычно проект запускается через команды `npm install` для предварительной загрузки недостающих на машине пакетов и непостредственно `npm start`.

Comment: Вам стоит отказаться от заказа, *"никогда не работал с файлами Phar, Composer, PHPUnit, Webpack"* и вообще создание этого вопроса однозначно говорят о том, что грамотно реализовать *"авторизацию/регистрацию"* у вас не выйдет со всеми вытекающими.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поставь nodejs и запускай (для dev-режима)

```
npm start
```

Если не получится, нужна секция `scripts` из `package.json`.

Comment: Я возможно все сделал правильно, но не знаю где его открывать в браузере. http://127.0.0.1: и localhost пробовал. Проект лежит в папке htdocs, xampp

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно знать порт, по которому работает express сервер обрабатывающий http запросы. Обычно в файле app.js внизу что то типа.

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('server is working'));

Значит сервер обрабатывает запрос к 3000 порту, и адрес будет http://localhost:3000

Естественно при этом должен быть запущен node, команда npm start из каталога с проектом, или команда node app.js из каталога проекта, или ng serve. Смотря что у вас указанно в теге scripts файлы package.json